# Multiple ios apps crash on launch without crashlog

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ios8, launch

Since today some of my ios apps crash on launch. The apps that are crashing are updated the a few weeks ago to make them ios8 compatible. It seems to crash on every device and every ios version (ios7.0 and higher). When connecting my device there is no crashlog.(Also no crashlog in iTunes connect and Google analytics) Rebuilding or reinstalling the app will fix the problem.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? Or another way to see what might cause the problem.

Comment: Do these apps happen to use Core Data? Sometimes if you modify your Core Data architecture without creating a new version that your app can migrate to it can cause crashes. Reinstalling the app would fix the issue since it would have the newer Core Data setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an app quits right at launch and there is no crash report available on the device this can have the following reasons:

1. There are already too many crash reports on the device and iOS simply doesn't create any more because of an internal limit. In that case you'll see the crash report shown in the console including a message that there are too many reports on the device and it doesn't save them into a file.
2. There is a provisioning profile issue. Code signature doesn't match the provisioning profile or the provisioning profile is expired. You'll have to inspect the devices console log for messages that appear at the time of launching the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there was a problem with my provisioning profile. However i check my profiles and everything was still good. Until i checked again this morning then everything was expired.

Answer (score 1):

Without any logs it's very difficult to determine your exact problem. I would suggest adding an error/crash reporting library to your application for the next release. A couple examples are Crashlytics and BugSense / Mint Splunk. I have been using Mint Splunk for the past six months and am very pleased with it.

In the meantime you can view the console of your store-installed application for any stack traces by doing the following:

1. Launch Xcode.
2. Connect your device.
3. Choose [Devices] from the 'Window' menu.
4. Select your device.
5. At the bottom portion of the screen you should see the console output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 3rd party services can not provide crash reports when the app isn't even launching or crashing shortly after launch (because the SDK then has no time to send the report to a server)

Comment: Thanks, i will use Mint Splunk or something in my next build.